# what does "fancy-ass" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What does **fancy-ass** mean in the following sentence:

> *And after that, getting hired by some "fancy-ass".*

Comment: Old related xkcd: [Hyphen](http://xkcd.com/37/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High standard, upmarket professional - or at least presenting themself as high standard, it's slightly derogatory.

eg. "He had a fancy-ass lawyer" = "he had an expensive, up market looking lawyer"

Answer (score 5):

I found way more than I ever wanted to know about the -ass suffix [here](http://everything2.com/title/The+-Ass+Suffix+and+Beyond). Basically, it serves as an intensifier.

Comment: 'nuff said!

Answer (score 3):

fancy-ass is usually used adjectivally, so the expression you use give is unusual, though it might be an ellipsis. "Get hired by some fancy-ass [manager]." In that case, "ass" is just being used as an intensifier. It would mean "Get hired by some very fancy manager."

"Ass" is not uncommon as an intensifier in very casual speech in American English. "Big-ass" meaning very big, "hard-ass" meaning very hard (though this has other meanings too) "kick-ass" meaning very good, and so forth.

Comment: Um. *-ass* isn't an intensifier in *kick-ass*. It's part of a composite term without which *kick* would be meaningless.

Comment: @FumbleFinger - It would be in "big-ass ass-kick" !

Comment: Sho' 'nuff would, you *bad-ass* mofo!